# "with"method inside Collection resource Called within another Collection resource doesn't return

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I have relations like

User  can haveMany Order ['user_id','id'].
Order can haveMany OrderDetail.
OrderDetail hasOne Product

- User ['id']
- Order ['user_id','id']
- OrderDetail ['order_id','product_id', 'quantity'].

Now I am using Collection Resource to get the required data

```
    $myOrder = new MyOrderCollection($this->order); //return
```

```
    // MyOrderCollection.php

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return 
        [
            'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($order)
             {
                    return
                    [
                        'id'=> $order->id,
                        'orderDetails' => new  MyOrderDetailCollection($order->orderDetails),
                    ];
            })
        ];
    }

    public function with($request)
    {
        return 
        [
            'meta' => 
            [
                'amount' => $amount // return total of all the orders of that user
            ]
        ];
    }
```

```
    // MyOrderDetailCollection.php

    public function toArray($request)
        {
            return
                $this->collection->transform(function($singleOrder)
                {
                    return 
                     [
                        'id' => $singleOrder->id,

                        'quantity'  => $singleOrder->quantity,
                        'total' => $total, // (quantity * price) return total price of single item of order
                        'product_details' => new ProductResource($singleOrder->product)
                    ];
                });
        }

        public function with($request)
        {
            return
            [
                'meta'=> 
                 [
                    'grand_total_of_a_order' => $this->collection->sum('total')
                 ]
            ];
        }
```

```
      //result

      {
        "data": 
         [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "orderDetails":
                [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "quantity": 7,
                        "total": 140,
                        "product_details": 
                        {
                           "price": 20
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "orderDetails": 
                 [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "total": 20,
                        "product_details": 
                        {
                            "price":10
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "quantity": 3,
                        "total": 90,
                        "product_details": 
                        {
                            "price":30
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "meta": 
            {
            "amount":
                {
                    "total" = 250 //calculated from another file 
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
 "meta": {
        "amount": {
            "grand_total_of_a_order" = xxx 
        }
    }
```

is not returned called from "with" method. and i thought that should be returned after order_details in the given response.

Why and How to solve?

Comment: This seems like correct json, your problem is that meta is in next to data column instead of the order details object?

Comment: no, The meta is correct as. but meta for the collection inside of the collection is not being shown. 
 "meta": {
        "amount": {
            "grand_total_of_a_order" = xxx 
        }
    }
not being shown, after order_details.  
ps. i think that is where is should have shown